# just "permission denied" error if connecting aws server with the use of pem file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have complete access of aws. I want to connect my server using .pem file example like below:

```
  ssh -i mypemfile.pem ubuntu@ec2-##-##-##-###.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Now problem is i have full access of amazon console but i have not .pem file.
I have generated new pem files by creating new keypairs but it won't worked.

[image]

my error code are like:

```html
D:\xampp\htdocs\mypic>ssh -vvv -i mypic.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-31-180-207.eu-west-1.compute.am
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file mypic.pem.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file mypic.pem type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp2
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha
4@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha
4@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 133/256
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/Users/Admin/AppD
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 3
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /c/Users/Admin/AppD
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 4
debug1: Host 'ec2-52-31-180-207.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/npm/.ssh
debug2: bits set: 501/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: mypic.pem (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: mypic.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

D:\xampp\htdocs\mypic>
```

Please help what to do for connection with aws console.

Sorry if my language is not proper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines (not all lines) and the last line of the pem file. I suspect your pem file format is incorrect.

Comment: @helloV : Yes please check below url:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/ZRV6PQF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path to the `.pem` file in a string

```
ssh -i "mypemfile.pem" ubuntu@ec2-##-##-##-###.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: That's already been done. OP states that in the question and the log shows `ssh -vvv -i mypic.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-`

Comment: the path to the pem file is wrapped in quotes, OP's own isn't, wrapping in quotes works for me, just connected some hours ago with it in quotes though

Comment: It makes no difference unless there are spaces in the filename.

Comment: i have generated new .pem file of existed instance. Does it will cause the problem?

Comment: probably because there's a place you can check the key attached to your instance, make sure it's the new key you generated

Answer (score 0):

Probably your SSH key has a wrong format. OpenSSH uses single line keys. 
You need generate new key with -i and -m options.

second option is your pem key hasn't read only access.  İf you try to connect with pem key has a write permission you cant connect to instance.

try this

```
chmod 400 xxx.pem
```